# Null pointer exception when using FragmentStatePagerAdapter in Java for Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

Within an IF statement, I am using data taken from a text file (using getTopics). If the data is there then it means that the fragment will have a corresponding tab in the action bar. When I added this however, I am receiving a null pointer exception. This occurs on the 3rd fragment to be added.

**Latest code that breaks:**

```
class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment=null;

    if(i==0) //This fragment always has a corresponding action bar tab.
    {
        fragment=new FragmentA();
    }

    addTabPosition = 2; //Variable used in getTopics().
    addTabTitle = "";
    GetTopics();
    if(i==1 && !(addTabTitle == ""))
    {
        fragment=new FragmentB();
    }
    addTabPosition = 3;
    addTabTitle = "";
    GetTopics();
    if(i==2 && !(addTabTitle == "")) //This is where the program breaks.
    {
        fragment=new FragmentC();
    }


    return fragment;
}
```

**Old code that does not break:**

```
    class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment=null;

    if(i==0)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentA();
    }

    if(i==1)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentB();
    }

    if(i==2)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentC();
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: You should post the error log from the crash

Comment: Also, was it your intention to run GetTopics() twice on each getItem() call, regardless of what the argument is? I don't know what your intention for this code was, but it looks like you've placed things you meant to be inside of 'if' statements outside of the statements.

Comment: I think you should use a nullsave way in your if-condition:
"".equals(addTabTitle)

Answer (score 0):

As i is a primitive int and can never be null, the problem must be with addTabTitle:

```
if(i==2 && !(addTabTitle == ""))
```

addTabTitle must be null which explains the exception. You will want to perform a null check like so:

```
if(i==2 && !(addTabTitle != null && addTabTitle == ""))
```

P.S. You may also wish to refactor your code a little as you are violating the DRY principle:

[Don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)